# What was the exact issue about booting Linux on Ryzen 3000 CPUs?

Tags: linux, systemd, boot, cpu, amd

As far as I understood, AMD Ryzen 3000 CPUs platform has (had, depending on your motherboard BIOS version) issues when booting Linux, especially regarding `systemd`, [apparently](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-3700x-3900x-linux&num=2).

I know AMD released a fix through a BIOS update but I was wondering if, apart from AMD employees, someone know what was the issue about, what was happening and what the fix was in the end.

Could someone explain to me what, exactly, was the problem? Does even someone, outside of AMD know?

Update:

I would be interested in knowing how this happened to be the case *in details*, I was not looking for a one-liner kind of answer.

If someone could provide a detailed explanation, this would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: I do not want to point fingers, but it seems like, from what I gathered even before asking my question here that AMD had, sometimes, a faulty implementation of `RDRAND` on some architectures (something that was already addressed by `systemd` in the past). What I am not sure to understand is how exactly it affects the OS, `systemd` and the boot itself.

Answer (score 1):

A problem of interaction between the 5.09 kernel, systemd, and [RDRAND](https://www.golem.de/news/linux-abstuerze-fehlerhafter-zufallsbefehl-auf-neuen-und-alten-amd-cpus-1907-142433.html) was resolved by a BIOS patch per [LinuxReviews](https://linuxreviews.org/AMD_Ryzen_3000_series_CPUs_can%27t_do_Random_on_boot_causing_Boot_Failure_on_newer_Linux_distributions), [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Releases-Linux-Zen2-Fix) and [Betanews](https://betanews.com/2019/07/13/amd-ryzen-3000-linux-problems/) websites and a [bug report at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1835809).  [AM4 microcode was implicated](https://www.techpowerup.com/257514/amd-agesa-1-0-0-3aba-buggy-company-pulls-it-from-motherboard-vendors). For specific details, please see the content of the links above.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: "While Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and older Linux distributions boot Zen 2, to date (poster) have not been able to successfully boot the likes of Ubuntu 19.04, Manjaro Linux, and Fedora Workstation 31. On all newer Linux distributions I've tried on two different systems built around the Ryzen 7 3700X and Ryzen 9 3900X, each time early in the boot process as soon as trying to start systemd services, all systemd services fail to start . I've confirmed with AMD they do have an open issue surrounding "5.0.9" (the stock kernel of Ubuntu 19.04) but as of writing hadn't shed any light into the issue..."

Comment: Should I really ask a member with such a good reputation here to elaborate *on your answer*? Do not take this wrong, but it seems like you are not trying... Your comment and quote are even longer than the actual one-line answer.

Comment: People should say thanks when they are given unearned time for free...

Comment: Regrettably, I am up to my ears to Things To Do in early January.